# "system-config-network-tui &" doesn't work

Tags: command-line, rhel, ip

When I try to edit or assign the IP using this command:

```
system-config-network-tui &
```

Terminal opens a console which is uncontrollable, just like this:

[image: Redhat]

This happens on CentOS and Red Hat.

Comment: @harish.venkat Great job It worked. Dear put this as an answer so I can accept it.Thanks and Good day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try not opening it as background process `system-config-network-tui` instead of `system-config-network-tui &` this has worked for me and later i switched to editing config files at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

Answer (score 2):

can use

```
    $ nmtui
```

command for this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't work ... It's a ncurses based program that uses a loop to refresh current  screen, you run it in background, you end up with a mess ..

If you just need to setup some IPs, why won't you just do it with `ifconfig` or `nmcli` (for network manager) ?